# Writing an HTTP serrver with context in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, http, server, basehttpserver

I'm trying to write an HTTP server in python 2.7. I'm trying to use ready-made classes to simplify the job (such as `SimpleHTTPServer`, `BaseHTTPRequestHandler`, etc.).

The server should listen for GET requests, and once it gets one - parse the request (the path and the arguments), and interact with an already initialized object (which accesses a DB, counts number of requests, etc.) - let's call it the 'handler', and return a response.

I understand that the RequestHandler class (e.g. `BaseHTTPRequestHandler`) will be constructed for each request. How can I pass the 'handler' to the handling routines, so that they could call its methods?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use a framework to further simplify your job. Here is an example in [flask](http://flask.pocoo.org):

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request

app = Flask(__name__)

your_handler = SomeHandlerClass()

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return your_handler.do_something_with(request)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

[`request`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#incoming-request-data) is a proxy object that holds all the incoming request data.